# Jquery search a div inside get response without any class or id

Tags: jquery, ajax

A dumb question, I know. But I have a problem. From a server I  make a js call and always get the response in div tags encapsulated  .

But the response is in JSON form 
so we have response variable data

```
data="<div> json_string_here</div>";
```

so how can i from it get only  json_string_here, and with not an escaped strings????

Comment: Use regular expression for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data returned is a string, you can use the following to extract the JSON and put it into an object

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON($(data).html());
```

EDIT:  Here's a jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/qV2Nw/2/

Comment: possiblly because jquery escapes the HTML and "" -> becomes &quot

Comment: I updated the question with a jsfiddle.  Make sure your JSON is in correct format.  Perhaps you can update your question with the content of the data variable in question?

Comment: data.text() alerts http://floomby.ru/content/g8ZFWg0iTE like this. seems the quotes are escaped in theese case also... how to unescape them ???

Comment: both are escaping quotes..... I am on 1.6 and on mobile environment here I updated the data on jsfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/qV2Nw/6/

Comment: that fiddle is working for me on Chrome, Firefox 8, & IE 8.  What mobile environment are you on?

Comment: Rhomobile ...I am sure the problem is in escaping of the double quotes.. How to de-escape them???

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with regular expressions in javascript... For,example

```
var data="<div> {\"hhh\":4, \"jjj\":[\"ghg\",\"ddd\"]}    </div>";
var patt = /\<div\>\s*(.*)\s*\<\/div\>/g;

document.write("Returned value: " + patt.exec(data)[1]);
```

And in a result you can get your json

```
Returned value: {"hhh":4, "jjj":["ghg","ddd"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is oddly worded but I will attempt to answer.

```
JSON.replace(/<div>/, "").replace(/<\/div>/, "");
```

You basically need to do some sort of find and replace on the information that is going into `data`.

Comment: JSON is my dummy variable for whatever the hell the variable is called that he is pulling in.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
jQuery.parseJSON($(data).html());
```

or by calling the URL to get the JSON Object you should use the $.getJSON() function, or when you do it by $.ajax, set the dataType:'json' that would also work, otherwise you can escape the  tags by Using Regular Expressions and then try the parse.JSON Function.